# Probability density function of $\max(U,\frac{1}{2})$, where $U\rightsquigarrow unif(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $U $ a random variable a random variable of uniform law on $[0,1]$. Let $V=\max (U,\frac{1}{2})$.

What is the law of $V$?

My idea:

$\max(U,\frac{1}{2})= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             U &  if  & U\ge \frac{1}{2}, \\
             \\ \frac{1}{2} &  if & U< \frac{1}{2} \\
                          \end{array}
   \right.$

$F_V(v)=P(V\le v)=P(\max(U,\frac{1}{2})\le v)=P(U\le v)+P(\frac{1}{2}\le v)=?$

Answer (score 1):

$F_V(v)=v$ for $\frac{1}{2}\le v \le 1$.  $F_V(v)=0$ for $v\lt \frac{1}{2}$ and $F_V(v)=1$ for $v \gt 1$.  Be careful in getting the density function - there is a delta function at $v=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the argument of @herb steinberg the density function of $V$ is:
$$f_V(v)=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{1/2}(v)+\mathbb{1}_{[1/2,\; 1]}(v)$$